# How do I programmatically change the CSS link for HTML files in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, html, css

I have a HTML document with the following markup:

```
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" HREF="c87d971ab8bc48ee87f9ced1b1d5c6e2.css" CHARSET="ISO-8859-1" TYPE="text/css">
```

I'd like a solution in C# that would change the CSS to (the CSS file name changes every time):

```
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" HREF="other.css" CHARSET="ISO-8859-1" TYPE="text/css">
```

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Is this the only change you need to make? Are all the documents in a similar format?

Comment: "Efficient" as in "easiest to code" I presume?

Comment: So this is a .aspx page with c# behind the scenes? Or, are these two separate files: .html and .cs?

Comment: Would a string search and replace do the trick?

Comment: What Framework are you using? ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET?

Comment: well i want to transform only the html code and put it in cache. no asp .net. I would like to have the easiest to code and all the document are in similar format. and the origin css name change every time so i can do a simple search / replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

(quoted from their codeplex page)

Comment: and do you have a good example with HTML agility Pack to start with ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed set of html files use regular expressions. In general case use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Here's simple regex you can start with:

```
<LINK [^>]+ HREF="(?<name>\w+).css"
```

Answer (score 1):

Howzabout just a simple `String.Replace(oldstring, newstring)`? There are any number of functions in the string classes. What have you tried?

Comment: the oldstring change every time i don't think it is a good idea but thank your for your answer

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
  string original = @"<LINK REL=""STYLESHEET"" HREF=""c87d971ab8bc48ee87f9ced1b1d5c6e2.css"" CHARSET=""ISO-8859-1";      
      string[] data = original.Split(new string[]{"HREF","CHARSET"},StringSplitOptions.None);
      string final = string.Format("{0} HREF=\"other.css\" CHARSET{1}",data[0],data[2]);
```

Comment: Please stop suggesting edits that add no value to the post. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116741/formatting-as-virtue-vs-formatting-as-sin